# Postgresql rounding numeric value

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get an output of 3 decimal places out of the below query.

the output i'm getting is 2.2600

if I changed the parameter 4 to be 3 in round function below, the output will be 2.300

which is incorrect, it should be 2.26

```
Select date(time), 

    round((count(case WHEN status='404 NOT FOUND' THEN 1 END))
    /
    (count(*))::numeric,4) * 100 as error_percentage

from log GROUP BY date(time)
ORDER BY error_percentage DESC
```

Comment: use ceil function instead of round

Comment: That shows the number rounded as whole. I still want to show the first 3 decimal places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT date(time), 
    ROUND(100.0 * (count(*) FILTER(WHERE status='404 NOT FOUND'))/(count(*)),3) 
    as error_percentage
FROM log 
GROUP BY date(time)
ORDER BY error_percentage DESC
```